# Remote Storage Service: Can only select "Removable Media" as media type

Tags: windows-server-2003, lto-4, windows

I'm trying to set up a Windows Server 2003 Remote Storage Server with a bunch of LTO4 tapes and an HP 1840 LTO4 drive. I understand the theory behind it (transparently archive older files from a particular disk volume to tape) and am trying to make it work.

I already have the disk volume defined, and Windows can see the tape drive. I've used two tapes so far which are showing up in the 'Free' Media Pool, under 'LTO Ultrium'. There's another Media Pool called 'Remote Storage' which contains a pool 'Removable media'. This is empty.

My problem is that when I go through the setup wizard for remote storage, the only 'Media type' I can select is 'Removable media'. This appears to be the pool under the 'Remote Storage' media pool. For some reason, I can't put LTO4 tapes into this Removable Media pool. As a result, when I set everything up, nothing gets copied to tape, presumably because it doesn't think there's any media available.

I can set up a separate LTO4 pool under 'Remote Storage' and add my tapes to that, but I don't get the option to use that pool as a media type during the setup process.

This probably sounds a little convoluted, so apologies for that. But if anyone can help figure out how to use LTO4 tapes with Windows Remote Storage Service, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the next page I read after asking this was this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297475

It seems that with a simple registry tweak, you can get RSS to support LTO Ultrium tapes.